# Single Salesforce Flow for record creation, updation and also deletion

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, delete, process-automation, flow-builder

Are there any ways to make a single Salesforce flow work on Create, Update and Delete?

I know that Salesforce flow supports deletion separately but developers here might know some tricks to make the flow work for delete condition on the same flow of creation and updation.

Comment: Nope. You specify the condition for entry to the flow. Delete is always separate. You would need to create three flows to share the logic; one for create/update, one for delete and a subflow both invoke.